# Has anyone written a Fuzzy date match to catch data entry errors?

Tags: java, .net, plsql

I wrote a routine in PL/SQL to try and match dates where there might by typographical/data entry errors.

It works, but I would like to see if anyone has other/better ideas. The routine does not need to be in PL/SQL, as I read many languages.

```
  FUNCTION FUZZY_DATE_MATCH(IN_DATE_1 DATE, IN_DATE_2 DATE) RETURN NUMBER AS
    MONTH_1 NUMBER(2);
    MONTH_2 NUMBER(2);
    DAY_1 NUMBER(2);
    DAY_2 NUMBER(2);
    YEAR_1 NUMBER(4);
    YEAR_2 NUMBER(4);
    MATCH_SCORE NUMBER(3) := 0;
  BEGIN
    IF TRUNC(IN_DATE_1) = TRUNC(IN_DATE_2)
    THEN
      MATCH_SCORE := 100;
    ELSE
      IF ABS(TRUNC(IN_DATE_1) - TRUNC(IN_DATE_2)) < 2
      THEN
        MATCH_SCORE :=50;
      ELSE
        MONTH_1 := TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(IN_DATE_1,'MM'));
        MONTH_2 := TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(IN_DATE_2,'MM'));
        IF MONTH_1 = MONTH_2
        THEN
          MATCH_SCORE := MATCH_SCORE + 15;
        ELSE
          IF (ABS(MONTH_1 - MONTH_2) < 2) OR
             (TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(LPAD(MONTH_1,2,'0'),2,1)||SUBSTR(LPAD(MONTH_1,2,'0'),1,1)) = MONTH_2)
          THEN
            MATCH_SCORE := MATCH_SCORE + 7;
          END IF;
        END IF;
        DAY_1 := TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(IN_DATE_1,'DD'));
        DAY_2 := TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(IN_DATE_2,'DD'));
        IF DAY_1 = DAY_2
        THEN
          MATCH_SCORE := MATCH_SCORE + 10;
        ELSE
          IF (ABS(DAY_1 - DAY_2) < 2) OR
             (TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(LPAD(DAY_1,2,'0'),2,1)||SUBSTR(LPAD(DAY_1,2,'0'),1,1)) = DAY_2)
          THEN
            MATCH_SCORE := MATCH_SCORE + 5;
          END IF;
        END IF;
        YEAR_1 := TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(IN_DATE_1,'YYYY'));
        YEAR_2 := TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(IN_DATE_2,'YYYY'));
        IF YEAR_1 = YEAR_2
        THEN
          MATCH_SCORE := MATCH_SCORE + 25;
        ELSE
          IF (ABS(YEAR_1 - YEAR_2) < 2) OR
             (TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(LPAD(YEAR_1,2,'0'),4,1)||SUBSTR(LPAD(YEAR_1,2,'0'),3,1)) = TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(YEAR_2),3)))
          THEN
            MATCH_SCORE := MATCH_SCORE + 12;
          END IF;
        END IF;
      END IF;
    END IF;
    RETURN MATCH_SCORE;
  END FUZZY_DATE_MATCH;
```

The basic concept is to compare two dates and return a value between 0 and 100 where 100 is an exact match and 0 is no match. The types of errors I am looking for are single digit errors, and transposition errors. My assumption is that years have more weight than months, which in turn have more weight than days.

I tried googling fuzzy date matching, but the answers typically deal with distance between dates as opposed to data entry errors.

AAll help is appreciated.

Paul

Answer (score 1):

No need to implement it yourself.  Take a look at the UTL_MATCH package which is a standard part of Oracle.  Here's a quick summary:

```
FUNCTION edit_distance(s1 IN VARCHAR2, s2 IN VARCHAR2)
                       RETURN pls_integer;
  -- Computes the Levenshtein distance between s1 and s2.

FUNCTION jaro_winkler(s1 IN VARCHAR2, s2 IN VARCHAR2)
                      RETURN binary_double;
  -- Similar to Levenshtein distance, but tries to account for mis-typings,
  -- character swaps, etc.

FUNCTION edit_distance_similarity(s1 IN VARCHAR2, s2 IN VARCHAR2)
                                  RETURN pls_integer;
  -- Similar to Levenshtein distance, but returns an integer from 0 to 100
  -- where 0 means no similarity and 100 means the strings are identical.

FUNCTION jaro_winkler_similarity(s1 IN VARCHAR2, s2 IN VARCHAR2)
                                 RETURN pls_integer;
  -- Similar to above, but based on Jaro-Winkler.
```

Here's a quick example:

```
SELECT UTL_MATCH.EDIT_DISTANCE('potato', 'tomato') AS lev,
       UTL_MATCH.EDIT_DISTANCE_SIMILARITY('potato', 'tomato') AS lev_sim,
       TO_NUMBER(UTL_MATCH.JARO_WINKLER('potato', 'tomato')) AS jw,
       UTL_MATCH.JARO_WINKLER_SIMILARITY('potato', 'tomato') jw_sim
  FROM DUAL;
```

Sounds to me like you might be able to use JARO_WINKLER_SIMILARITY.  Convert both the dates to a standard string representation (e.g. TO_CHAR(aDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) and then compare them.

(Incidentally - the `TO_NUMBER` is applied to the results of `JARO_WINKLER` because Oracle throws an `ORA-031115 : unsupported network datatype or representation` when JARO_WINKLER is called because it returns a BINARY_DOUBLE, which the Oracle interface routines on the Windows platform can't seem to deal with. So why HAVE the type if you can't USE the type?  ???  :-)

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

If you're correcting data entry errors then there probably isn't any advantage to weighting the different date parts - I'm assuming that it's equally likely that there will be a keying error on the year part as on the day part.  As such this is a fuzzy string matching problem instead of a fuzzy date matching problem.

A commonly used set of algorithms for fuzzy string matching is the [edit distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) - [Hamming distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) is fast but assumes that the incorrect string doesn't contain any character additions/removals (so it will perform well on comparing "hello" and "gello", but not on comparing "hello" and "hhello"), whereas [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) is more expensive to calculate but is able to account for character additions/removals in the incorrect string.

Comment: Not really correcting data errors. This is actually a part of a larger routine that is trying to find matches between people where all I have are Name (first,last, middle), Address, Date Of Birth and Gender. I am using Jaro-Winkler and Edit-Distance routines for the text fields, but thought something more date specific might be better.

Comment: Gotcha, in that case it makes probably makes sense to weight the different date parts

Answer (score 0):

I had the same search so I will share my version of the date function 
`  See code DateMatch:

```
 CREATE Function [fn_DateMatch] (@dt1 DateTime, @dt2 DateTime)
 RETURNS FLOAT 
   AS 
 BEGIN
 DECLARE @Result FLOAT, @yyyy1 NUMERIC, @yyyy2 NUMERIC, @mm1 NUMERIC, @mm2 NUMERIC, @dd1 NUMERIC, @dd2 NUMERIC, @threshold NUMERIC  
   SELECT @Result = 0, @threshold = 85 
   IF @dt1 = @dt2 SET @Result = 100 
   IF (@Result < 100) SET @Result = 100-abs(DATEDIFF (DAY,@dt1, @dt2)) 
   IF (@Result < @threshold)
   BEGIN 
     SELECT @yyyy1 = CONVERT (INT, DATEPART (year, @dt1)), @mm1 = CONVERT  (INT, DATEPART (month, @dt1)), @dd1 = CONVERT  (INT, DATEPART (day, @dt1)) 
          , @yyyy2 = CONVERT (INT, DATEPART (year, @dt2)), @mm2 = CONVERT  (INT, DATEPART (month, @dt2)), @dd2 = CONVERT  (INT, DATEPART (day, @dt2))
     SET @Result = 100-((@yyyy1+@yyyy2)*3.0+(@mm1+@mm2)*3.0+(@dd1+@dd2)*1.0)*3
     IF (@Result < @threshold) and @yyyy1=@yyyy2 and @mm1+@dd1=@mm2+@dd2 SET @Result = 90
   END 
   IF (@Result < @threshold) 
     BEGIN  
     IF convert(varchar, @dt1, 108) <> '00:00:00' and convert(varchar, @dt2, 108) <> '00:00:00' 
        BEGIN
          SET @Result = 100-((CONVERT(float, dbo.fn_levenshtein (convert(varchar, @dt1, 120), convert(varchar, @dt2, 120)))/CONVERT(float,len(convert(varchar, @dt2, 120))))*100) 
        END 
     ELSE  
        BEGIN 
          SET @Result = 100-((CONVERT(float, dbo.fn_levenshtein (convert(varchar, @dt1, 112), convert(varchar, @dt2, 112)))/CONVERT(float,len(convert(varchar, @dt2, 112))))*100) 
        END 
     END 
   RETURN @Result 
 END;`
```